# Query only if non-boolean argument exists

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to find a way to achieve include multiple queries in the same query based on required arguments.
This might be confusing, so let's take a look at an example

If we have 2 resolvers both with required IDs, let's say:

```
post(id: ID!) {...}
user(id: ID!) {...}
```

And we want to fetch both within the same query/request, but we might or not have an ID like the user, something as:

```
query($postId: ID!, $userId: ID) {
  post(id: $postId) { ... }
  user(id: $userId) { ... }
}
```

Now if we look we see that `$user: ID` is not mandatory in the query, but it is in the resolver.

---

I've looked at [`@include` and `@skip` directives](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives) although, I didn't find a way to convert the `$userId` to a boolean.

Also, I've tried to pass a boolean as `shouldIncludeUser` although, as expected, the GQL will complain that the variable `$userId` of type `ID` doesn't match the type `ID!`.

---

Any ideas ?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The way I am getting around this is by passing in two parameters to my GraphQL query, as you say in your question. I make them both mandatory:

```
query($userId: ID!, $useUserId: Boolean!)
```

In the JavaScript that calls this query, I'm doing something like this:

```js
  const variables = {
    userId: userId || "", // If you don't set this parameter to something, it fails at runtime.
    useUserId: !!userId,
  };
```

I don't love this, but it's working fine. A second approach I considered is having two queries where the main body is shared with a fragment. One of the two queries has the conditional query and I decide at execution time which to use.

I feel like this functionality should exist in GraphQL, and the fact that it doesn't means that we're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I ended up in the same place. Although as you mention too _"I don't love this"_, so instead I just used 2 queries. ‍♂️


_"means that we're probably doing something wrong"_, I wouldn't say that, there are (non-hackish) work arounds, like 2 separated queries work, or just handling the use case of missing the required ID in the backend, so it might not be a big priority.


Also, it's always evolving, the union input topic was 1st discussed (to my knowledge) in 2017, and finally we have the `@oneof` RFC but is still not yet out there.